# How to make UIBarButtonItem same click effect as UIButton?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

How to make UIBarButtonItem with properties(Style: Bordered and Identifier: Custom ) click effect (like the UIButton selected  state) ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton button...];
...

UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [UIBarButtonItem initWithCustomView:button];
```

[See apple's documents](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: You could even cut it down to one line with `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [UIBarButtonItem initWithCustomView:[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]];`

Comment: Meh.  He said effect, not substance. ;P

Comment: UIBarButtonItem is not derived from UIControl... Everybody can make UICustomBarButtonItem to support "selected state effect". But it will take many time to write code.